# Release PostgeSQL connection Pool in Nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, postgresql, express

I am trying to connect my application to the database using the connection pool method, its connecting fine, and data insertion is happening fine without any issues but other queries in the same file are slowing down.

I have tried with release() method also not working properly.

How can release the pool to the next query once it's executed the current query?

Below is my dbpool.js file code where I am writing a common generalized database connection,

```
var pg = require('pg');

var PGUSER = 'postgres';
var PGDATABASE = 'test_database';

var config = {
    user: PGUSER, // name of the user account
    host: 'localhost',
    database: PGDATABASE, // name of the database
    password: 'password@AWS',
    port: 5432,
    max: 10, 
    idleTimeoutMillis: 10000 
};

const pool = new pg.Pool(config);

const DB = {
    query: function(query, callback) {

        pool.connect((err, client, done) => {
              if(err){ return callback(err); }
              client.query(query, (err, results) => {
                 // done();
                 client.release();
                 
                 // if(err) { console.error("ERROR: ", err) }
                 if(err) { return callback(err); }
                 
                 callback(null, results.rows);
             })
        });
    }
};

module.exports = DB;
```

I tried with both the done() and client.release() method but no luck. If I use both then I am getting an error message client is already released.

Below is my socket.js file code:

```
var express = require('express');
const connection = require('./dbpool.js');

if(arData == '0022'){
    const queryText = "INSERT INTO alert(alert_data) VALUES('"+arData+"')";
    connection.query(queryText,(err, res) => {
       if(err){
           console.log(err.stack);
       }
    });
}

if(arData == '0011'){
    const queryText = "INSERT INTO table2(alert_data) VALUES('"+arData+"')";
    connection.query(queryText,(err, res) => {
       if(err){
           console.log(err.stack);
       }
    });
}

function ReverseCommunication(){
     const select1 = "SELECT * FROM alert WHERE action = '0' ORDER BY alert_id ASC LIMIT 1";
     connection.query(select1, (err, res) =>{
        if(err) {
            console.log("Error1");
            res.json({"error":true});
        }
        else{
            console.log("res==",res);
        }
     });
}

setInterval(function(){
    ReverseCommunication();
}, 2000)
```

Answer (score 0):

With pool you shouldn't need to close the connection. With pool it will reuse the connection pool for subsequent request so you don't have to connect to the DB each time.

(i'm not a PG expert here, sure other could expand on that way better then I )

What works for us is to set up the dbpool file you have like this

```
const {Pool,Client} = require('pg');

const pool = new Pool({
user: process.env.POSTGRES_USER,
host: process.env.POSTGRES_URL,
database: process.env.POSTGRES_DATABASE,
password: process.env.POSTGRES_PASSWORD,
port:  process.env.POSTGRES_PORT,
keepAlive: true,
connectionTimeoutMillis: 10000, // 10 seconds
max: 10
});
pool.connect()
.then(() => console.log('pg connected'))
.catch(err => console.error(err))

module.exports  =  pool
```

Then use the pool.query like you have now with pool.connect

Also, just a side note what lib are you using for PG? Noticed your queries are dynamic, you may want to adjust those to prevent possible SQL-injection.